Why is the total energy of a bound system w.r.t to its COM less than zero?
This question came to me when i was trying to solve the following problem,

Consider two identical particles each of mass $m$ held at a separation $r_0$ in free space. One of them is given a velocity $v_0$ perpendicular to $r_0$ and the other one is simultaneously released. For what range of velocity $v_0$ will the masses be bound in orbital motion under their mutual gravitational forces.

I tried solving this for quite some time using work energy theorem however could not produce the right answer, when i looked at its solution it stated without any proof that the total energy in a bound system w.r.t to the CM is less then zero.
I could not quite understand why this would be the case, i tried reasoning that since the system is bound its kinetic energy cannot exceed its gravitational potential energy other wise the system would separate to infinity however why should this fact not hold in the ground frame, after the statement of this fact the solution proceeds as follows by making the total energy less then 0 and obtaining that the range of velocities is,
$$v < 2\sqrt{\frac{Gm}{r}}$$
Also in another question which came right after which is as follows,

In free space, two identical particles A and B are rigidly attached at the ends of a light rigid rod of length $r_0$ and another identical particle C is held at a position in such a way that the locations of the particles makes an equilateral triangle. The particle C is given a velocity $v_0$ tangential to the circumscribing circle of the triangle and the other two are released simultaneously. For what range of velocity $v_0$ will the two particles be bound under their mutual gravitational forces.

I tried to solve this problem using the above concept however it came out wrong, the reason being when i looked at the solution, that the "self-energy" of the rigid body this is the dumbbell was ignored reducing a term in the potential energies, i also failed to understand why this was done.
Could someone please explain to me why the first fact is true and only true in the CM frame as doing the same in the ground frame does not yield the same answer!
Any help would be highly appreciated!.

It is a consequence of how $0$ energy is defined.
In general, energy differences are important. A rock rolls downhill because it loses potential energy. Current flows in a circuit because of the potential difference between the terminals of a battery.
In such cases, the absolute energy is not important. A rock will roll $10$ meters down a high mountain as easily as it will roll down the same terrain on a small hill.
We can set the zero point of energy wherever we like. This is implicit in $E=mgh$. $E=0$ where $h=0$. For a weight falling from a table to the floor, we might set $h=0$ at the floor. For a rock rolling down a hill, we might see $h=0$ at sea level.
This means negative absolute energies are possible. The rock can roll below sea level in Death Valley.
For a collection of particles that attract each other, the convenient place to define $E=0$ is when the particles are separated infinitely far apart. The forces are $0$. If you substitute in particles that don't attract each other and let them approach each other, you still have $0$ potential energy. If the particles do attract each other as they approach, you wind up at the same positions with $E<0$. So this makes sense as the potential energy due to the attractive forces.
Another way to see why $E=0$ was chosen when the particles were infinitely separated is where else would be better. For many system, potential energy keeps dropping as particles approach. As the distance approaches $0$, $E \rightarrow -\infty$. There is no other obvious set of separations to set the value of $E$. So setting $E$ at infinite separation is reasonable. Choosing $E=0$ there is the most convenient choice. But fundamentally, it is just a convention.

First, I am going to name the frame (which you could have done). $S$ is the initial frame in which the masses are held in "free space". $S'$ is the COM frame.
A bound system is one that won't reach "infinity", maybe more formally, $r_i < \infty$, though I am not sure if the mathematicians will tolerate that language.
If we work in $S$, then we have a stationary mass:
$$ {\bf r}_1(t=0) = (0, 0) $$
$$ {\bf \dot r}_1(t=0) = (0, 0) $$
and the moving one:
$$ {\bf r}_0(t=0) = r_0{\bf \hat x} $$
$$ {\bf \dot r}_0(t=0) = v_0{\bf \hat y} $$
The problem here is that for any $v_0\ne 0$, as $t \rightarrow \infty$:
$$ |{\bf r}_i| \rightarrow \infty $$
So, we have to amend our understanding of "unbound", and say:
$$ |{\bf r}_1 -{\bf r}_0| \rightarrow \infty $$
Now we have two variable that are guaranteed to be unbound, but we want to know that there difference is finite or not:
$$ \infty - \infty < \infty $$
or
$$ \infty - \infty \ge \infty $$
That is ugly.
The obvious move is to define new coordinates, in which our problem is separable:
$$ {\bf r} \equiv {\bf r}_1 - {\bf r}_0 $$
$$ {\bf R} \equiv \frac 1 2 ({\bf r}_1 + {\bf r}_0) $$
and the question of finiteness applies only to $|{\bf r}|$.
Meanwhile, ${\bf R}$ is just the center-of-mass coordinate and we can ignore it.
The easiest way to ignore it is to choose a frame where:
$$ {\bf R}(t) = (0, 0) $$
and that is $S'$.

could i ask what is $\vec{r_i}$ in this situation?

$i$ runs over particles indices under consideration, and the vector difference is the displacement between the position of the particle and an origin for a coordinate system.

Because that's how we define potential energy. In reality you could add any constant but it would still give you same EOM. What matters is the gradient of that function. And for simplicity it is taken to be 0 at infinity, but let's say you want to solve the motion of these two particles. The potential energy of the interaction of two particles depends only on
the distance between them, i.e. on the magnitude of the difference in their
radius vectors. The Energy of such a system is therefore:
\begin{equation}
E = \frac{1}{2} m_1 \dot{\mathbf{r}}_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_2 \dot{\mathbf{r}}_2^2 + U(|\mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2|).
\end{equation}
Let $\mathbf{r} \equiv \mathbf{r}_1 - \mathbf{r}_2$ be the relative position vector, and let the origin be at the
centre of mass, i.e.
\begin{equation}
m_1 \mathbf{r}_1 + m_2 \mathbf{r}_2 = 0.
\end{equation}
These two equations give:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{r}_1 = \frac{m_2 \mathbf{r}}{m_1 + m_2}, \quad 
\mathbf{r}_2 = -\frac{m_1 \mathbf{r}}{m_1 + m_2}.
\end{equation}
Substituting gives:
\begin{equation}
E = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{\mathbf{r}}^2 + U(r),
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
m = \frac{m_1 m_2}{m_1 + m_2}.
\end{equation}
From here you can work on an equivalent one body problem and the restated condition will be that $r$ doesn't go to infinity (Two particles stay bound to each other).
Path of this now "single" particle in a central field lies in one plane (Because angular momentum $M$ is conserved) . Using polar
coordinates $(r, \phi)$ in that plane, we can write the Energy as
\begin{equation}
E = \frac{1}{2} m \left( \dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\phi}^2 \right) + U(r)
\end{equation} Now using \begin{equation}
M = m r^2 \dot{\phi} = \text{constant}.
\end{equation}
and substituting $\dot{\phi}$ back into the Energy equation
\begin{equation}
E=\frac{1}{2} m \dot{r}^2 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{M^2}{m r^2} + U(r).
\end{equation} We further reduce the problem to a single dimensional problem, where the effective potential is given by:
\begin{equation}
U_{\text{eff}} = U(r) + \frac{M^2}{2 m r^2}.
\end{equation}
Now, in a given single dimensional problem it is very clear that the motion is bound only if total energy $E<0$. If you draw a graph of $U_{\text{eff}}$ against $r$ and also Plot a line $E=const$ on the same graph, the intersection points will exactly give you the points between which the motion of a particle is bound. You can read further into this in Laundau/Lifshitz mechanics book.
